# Unitialized Constant error when using forked activemerchant gem via Gemfile/github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, gemfile, activemerchant

This morning I forked the activemerchant Ruby gem b/c of a change I needed for my app.  My gemfile used to be...

```
gem 'activemerchant', '~> 1.53.0'
```

Now it's...

```
gem 'activemerchant', :github => 'ajporterfield/active_merchant'
```

However, after running bundle update activemerchant and restarting my Rails server, I'm getting and uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Billing::PaypalExpressGateway error.

I am using the Paypal gateway, but my change was a one-liner in the BluePay gateway so I don't think I caused the error with my code change.

Is there an obvious step I'm missing in order to reference a gem from Github in my gemfile?

I'm using Rails 4, Ruby 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After revisiting this, I realized my mistake.  I had already forked the activemerchant gem - a long time ago.  So to fix, I deleted my forked repo and re-forked.  Everything's working for me as expected now.